# One arm rotating strangely in rig

Tags: rigging

I have a video of the problem [here.](https://streamable.com/64adjl)

I am unsure why this is; the rigging is identical to the left side, which does not have this problem.  Both the left and right upper arms are parented to the upper spine.  I checked the weights and that is not the problem.  As shown in the video, when I move the hand and forearm, the bones react normally, but when I move the upper arm or any other part of the body the arm rotates strangely.  Please help me fix this problem!

Comment: It looks like *right arm* is influenced by IK (as well as both legs), not the *left arm*. Maybe something wrong in your IK of left arm ?

Comment: Ah yes, the IK does seem to be part of the problem, thank you!  I realized that the chain lengths in each were different (2 on the right arm, 0 on the left).  I'll play around with this and see if I can figure it out.  Thank you for this!